# Is there a zikr that can erase major sins

Tags: allah, sin, punishment, forgiveness, dhikr

I have committed major sins in the past but now want to achive forgiveness please tell me is there any zikr that can help me from erasing major sins? I will also do tauba

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it means that you regret what you have done in the past and intend to repent. In the Qur'an, God says to the Prophet: Say [that Allah declares,] ‘O My servants who have committed excesses against their own souls, do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed Allah will forgive all sins. Indeed, He is the All-forgiving, the All-merciful.39_v53.

Moreover, your Lord will indeed be forgiving and merciful to those who repent after they having committed evil out of ignorance and reform themselves.16_v119

So do not worry about God's forgiveness. He forgives. The first sign of accepting your repentance is to see that you will no longer commit those great sins. This means that your repentance is real.
How to repent of different sins is different; Because there are two major sins, the right of God and the right of the people.

The method of repentance from the sins that are the right of God is real repentance and the intention to leave permanently and not to repeat it, and in cases where an obligatory act has been abandoned, make up for that obligatory act; Such as performing the prayers that he has not prayed and the fasts that he has not fasted, etc., and in the case of sins that are the right of the people, in addition to repentance and remorse, he must fulfill the right of the people, unless the rightful one overrides his right and makes it lawful.
That is, if someone's right is lost or someone's reputation is lost, or if someone or a group has deviated from the right path because of your propaganda, you should. Let them know.

https://makarem.ir/main.aspx?lid=0&typeinfo=42&catid=29319&pageindex=0&mid=321218#114727564_2

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well.

> Ibn Mas'ud (May Allah be pleased with him) said:
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "He who says: 'Astaghfir ullah-alladhi la ilaha illa Huwal-Haiyul-Qayyumu, wa atubu ilaihi (I seek the forgiveness of Allah, there is no true god except Allah, the Ever-Living, the Self- Subsisting, and I turn to Him in repentance),' **his sins will be forgiven even if he should have run away from the battlefield (while he was engaged in fighting for the Cause of Allah).**" [Abu Dawud, At-Tirmidhi and Al-Hakim (on conditions of Al-Bukhari and Muslim for accepting Hadith)]. https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1874

Fleeing from the battlefield is a major sin.

> Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Avoid the seven sins that doom a person to Hell.” We said: What are they, O Messenger of Allah? He said: “Associating others with Allah (shirk); witchcraft; killing a soul whom Allah has forbidden us to kill, except in cases dictated by Islamic law; consuming orphans’ wealth; consuming riba; **fleeing from the battlefield**; and slandering chaste, innocent women.”  (Reported in Bukhari and Muslim)

So from this we can deduce we will be forgiven our major sins if we recite the supplication from above.

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.